# Selenium Webdriver VBA - New Loop for Error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Goodnight

I would like some help if possible. I'm putting this code together, but I'm not able to create an output if it doesn't find the page item. I would like if he doesn't find the intem he would go to the next line, not displaying an error message as I have a lot of data to capture.

````
Dim drive As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim ks As Selenium.Keys
Dim tempo As Integer
Set ks = New Selenium.Keys

site = "http://www.google.com"


Plan1.Select


tell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Line = 4



drive.Start
drive.Get site

Do Until Cells(Linha, 1) = ""


For Line = 4 To tell
Number = Range("A" & Linha).Value


drive.SwitchToFrame drive.FindElementById("WIDGET_ID_4")

Set telephone = drive.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/.........")

Range("B" & Line).Value = telephone.Attribute("outerText")


drive.SwitchToDefaultContent






Next Linha


Loop



drive.Quit

MsgBox "Process Ok"


End Sub```
````

Comment: Where does the error occur? Which line? This one? `Range("B" & Line).Value = telephone.Attribute("outerText")`

Comment: Hello. No.. i erro occur in drive.SwitchToFrame drive.FindElementById("WIDGET_ID_4") tanks

Comment: I want if he doesn't find that tab. it goes to the next line . Thanks Qharr

Comment: You keep looking for the same tab though (same id). Should this change? With current logic it would then make sense to simply exit the loop, if tab not found, as the element isn't going to suddenly appear (based on shown code). You also don't do anything with `Number`.

Comment: no.. i would look for another id

Comment: Is the end of the ID supposed to match `Line` e.g. `WIDGET_ID_4` then `WIDGET_ID_5` then 6....?

Comment: that's right.. only he has to return the id that he is working one more to continue the work

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop, test if the tab is found i.e. if not *tab* is nothing then do stuff.....else move to next id. Wrap the SET line in an On Error Resume Next On Error GoTo 0 pair to suppress potential element not found exception.

I think linha should be line and Number be used to set the next id.

Please do note that using unqualified ranges e.g. Range without specifying the worksheet, you are implicitly referencing the current ActiveSheet and this is bug-prone.

```
Do Until Cells(Line, 1) = vbNullString

    For Line = 4 To tell
    
        Number = Range("A" & Line).Value

        Dim targetTab As webElement
        
        On Error Resume Next 'suppress potential exception
        Set targetTab = drive.FindElementById("WIDGET_ID_4")     
        On Error GoTo 0 'switch exception raising back on

        If Not targetTab Is Nothing Then 'test if reference obtained for target element
        
            drive.SwitchToFrame targetTab

            Set telephone = drive.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/.........")

            Range("B" & Line).Value = telephone.Attribute("outerText")
  
            drive.SwitchToDefaultContent
            Set targetTab = Nothing
        End If

    Next Line

Loop
```

Comment: It didn't work.. It locks the code if it doesn't find Set targetTab = drive.FindElementById("WIDGET_ID_".  I even apologize if I didn't express myself correctly.. I need that if it doesn't find this WIDGET_ID_4 it moves on to the next search number. Because in the capture that I'm doing, some numbers are blocked, and I need to skip them to continue with the scrapping. The number has nothing to do with the widget. The number is a search key that will be included at the beginning of the code. As some numbers are blocked, this WIDGET_4 will not be available on the page, 
 possible verification

Comment: So WIDGET_4 remains constant. How does Number fit in? Your current code loops but doesn't do anything with the other variables. I think there is some logic missing from the question that would help make sense of it. It WIDGET is constant then just change to `Set targetTab = drive.FindElementById("WIDGET_ID_4")`

Comment: I made this replacement and it gives an error if it doesn't find it. As for the number.. I haven't written that part of the code yet.. it will stay first of all.. it will be like this.

Drive. get URL
Drive. SendKeys("number")

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: If Not drive.FindElementById("WIDGET_ID_4") Is Nothing Then

NoSuchElementError
Element not Found for Id=WIDGET_ID_4

Exactly what I wanted to pass, when it doesn't find that specific element, go to the next number. Thanks

Comment: Show... it worked very well.. thank you very much. Can you explain to me what you did? For me to learn.. I have another question, if possible help me.. I didn't even elaborate the code or if it's easier to use a function in excel.

Comment: In the attribute that I pull from the text in the html comes several "\n \n \n \n \n \n\n \n\n that ends up in excel I understand as space or tab .. it would be possible in vba to make it only capture letters and numbers of this attribute or is it better for me to do a trim later in excel itself

Comment: Are you targeting the right element/attribute would be my first question given the number of \n? You can use `Trim$(telephone.Attribute("outerText"))`.  Without seeing the relevant html unsure at present.

Comment: As per edit to answer text, I suppressed the exception, then tested if an element reference existed. I've annotated the relevant lines in the code now as well.

Comment: the trim worked.. but it was the middle of the sentence..

Comment: That's not how TRIM works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions

Comment: Sorry my very bad english.. i m using a Translator.  the sentence was wrong.. at the ends it worked... where it didn't work was in the middle of the text

Comment: You need to edit your question with the relevant html as actual html not as an image so it can be used for testing. Or provide the url to test with. You might also consider using Replace$.